# How many ships would a late medieval/early modern port see in a year?

Tags: medieval, ships, sea

I'm working on a story that involves a character searching through logbooks from a seaport in a mid-sized, bustling city (think a largish city in late medieval/early modern Europe, pre-industrial revolution but well into the process of colonizing the rest of the world).

I've been having trouble with some basic numbers--how many ships would be entering and leaving a major seaport from this period on a regular basis? How many would be stopping over vs. starting out? How many ships would be docked at any given time?

Comment: a) that's not a question for worldbuidling b) a good question for history.se c) if you choose port. Venice would see much different traffic than Dunwich

Comment: I agree with @SZCZERZOKŁY; while this is certainly a good question, you will be better served on History.SE.

Comment: You might could find drawings of original docks and estimate their size from maps.  Given that and length of ships of the age, estimate max capacity of the docks.  We people tend to build things to fit their needs.

Answer (score 5):

Seaborne commerce increased dramatically between the end of the Middle Ages and the dawn of the Age of Machines...

From the [History of the Port of London pre 1908](http://www.pla.co.uk/Port-Trade/History-of-the-Port-of-London-pre-1908) by the Port of London Authority:

> *"During the eighteenth century the rate of increase of the volume of the trade of the Port fluctuated with the alternating periods of peace and war. Marked progress took place during the closing years. Between 1700 and 1770 the commerce of the Port was nearly doubled and from 1770 to 1795 (only 25 years) it again doubled. In 1792 imports into England amounted to £17,898,000 and exports £23,674,000. London’s share was £12,072,000 and £14,743,000 respectively, or nearly 65 per cent. of the whole. The greatest increases in commodities imported were sugar, rum, dyewoods, ginger and pimento from the West Indies.*
> *Some idea of the state of congestion that existed in the river at this time may be gathered from the fact that in the Upper Pool, **1,775** vessels were allowed to moor simultaneously in a space adapted for about **545**. It must be remembered that a ship of 500 tons was spoken of at this time as a ship of very exceptional size and this partly explains the state of congestion."*

Wim Blockmans, Mikhail Krom, and Justyna Wubs-Mrozewicz [*The Routledge Handbook of Maritime Trade around Europe 1300-1600: Commercial Networks and Urban Autonomy*](https://books.google.ro/books?id=WiglDwAAQBAJ&dq=port+venice+traffic+1600) (link goes to Google Books) gives the following data for the port of Genoa in the 16th century (p. 165):

- Tonnage of ships registered in Genoa, maximum: 29,000 tons. (That's about 150 ships of 200 tons burthen each.)
- Average tonnage of imported cargo per year: 56,000 tons. (That's about 280 ships of 200 tons burthen each.)

Ah, and regarding the question *"how many [ships] would be stopping over vs. starting out"*: the two numbers are obviously just about equal -- new ships being launched or old ships being retired are relatively rare events. Most of the time, a ship coming into port will get out of port again.

Comment: Two ships enter, one ship leaves. Not a port I want to go to, like bars...and hospitals. Anywhere really.